# Python: SpatiaLite table to numpy recarray with datetime format?

Tags: python, qgis, spatialite, numpy

I posted this question at the [QGIS-user forum](http://forum.qgis.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9473&sid=0ef10d883b88a82ffad1ba9c921faa2c) but it might be too technical, thus I take a chance and try here as well.

My plan is to have a QGIS plugin that reads and plots time series data corresponding to selected points in a vector layer(the points represents different measuring stations and I need to quickly view the time series from each and one of them, sometimes several stations in same plot). Consequently I need Python to read time series data from a Spatialite table and then plot it with Matplotlib.plot:

```
from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as sqlite 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import datetime

MyPath = r"C:\DATA\DBTEST\MyTestDb.sqlite"
conn = sqlite.connect(MyPath,detect_types=sqlite.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite.PARSE_COLNAMES)
curs = conn.cursor()

sql = r"""SELECT Date as 'date [datetime]', Level_masl FROM MyTable"""
rs = curs.execute(sql)
recs = rs.fetchall()

My_format = [('date_time', datetime.datetime), ('values', float)]
table = np.array(recs, dtype=My_format)
table2=table.view(np.recarray)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(table2.date_time, table2.values, 'o-')
....
```

But it seems like I do not get the correct data types since matplotlib don't accept my 'date_time'. A print table2 is shown below, I guess the small u indicates that it is unicode and not datetime?

> print table2
>
> > recarray([(u'2011-04-20 09:42:00', 703.46000000000004),
> >     (u'2011-04-20 09:43:00', 705.35000000000002),
> >     ...
> >     dtype=[('date_time', '|O4'), ('values', '

I am no programmer and absolutely a complete Python and Spatialite beginner so any help would be very much appreciated!

/JK

Comment: Welcome to GIS.stackexchange @joskal! Since this question is not really GIS-specific, I'll migrate it to a more suitable site.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're trying to pass in a string.

Matplotlib has several convenience functions for converting date strings to it's (internal) datetime representation.

Try something more like:

```
...
from matplotlib.dates import datestr2num
...

...
time = datestr2num(table2.date_time)
ax.plot_date(time, table2.values, 'o-')
...
```

`plot_date` is the same as `plot`, it just automatically formats the x-axis to have time (e.g. hour, day, month, etc) labels.

If you'd rather use `plot` (or `bar`, etc) instead, just call `ax.plot(time, y, ...)` or `ax.bar` as usual, and then call `ax.xaxis_date()` afterwards to set up the date labels.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the best help from Joe Kington, thanks a lot!

Insert to original code in question:

```
myTimestring = []  
i = 0
for row in table2: 
    myTimestring.append(table2.date_time[i])
    i = i + 1
numtime=datestr2num(myTimestring)
...
ax.plot_date(numtime, table2.values, 'o-')
```

There are most certainly more elegant solutions than 'for row in...' but this works!